# Changing Spring Boot application version through gradle.properties while using Spring Boot gradle-plugin

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I'm using the Spring boot gradle plugin and have put this in my `application.yml`:

```
spring:
    application:
        name: myapp
        version: ${version}
```

I process the resource file for tokens using:

```
processResources {
  filesMatching('application.yml') {
    expand(project.properties)
  }
}
```

And I use this annotation in my controller:

```
public class MyController {
  @Value("${spring.application.version}")
  private String appversion
...
```

And it all works, yay!  The problem is that I can't figure out what is actually controlling the version because this reports version `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT` even though I specify a different `version` in `gradle.properties`.

I tried updating the [springBoot DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.3.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#running-your-application) thusly:

```
springBoot {
  buildInfo {
    properties {
      version = "${project.version}"
    }
  }
}
```

But it has no effect.  Could someone help me understand the proper way to increment/manage the version using the Spring Boot gradle plugin?

Comment: The way you defined the `application.yml` properties file and the `processResources` task configuration are correct: if the version you defined in `gradle.properties` file is not taken into account, this could mean that this version is overiden somewhere else: maybe you still have a `version` property defined directly in your `build.gradle` script (or root project script if you have multi-project build) ?

Comment: a quick way to test:  1) define  property version in build.gradle : `version=dummy`  2) execute Gradle task `processResources` 3) check content of  `/build/resources/main/application.yml`

Comment: Oh man, you're a seer!  Sure enough I had a version defined in the `build.gradle` that I missed.  Nice to have a separate set of eyes at SOF.  What a relief!  Please respond as an answer and I'll confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said  in my comment, the way you have set the version in `gradle.properties` and how you configured the `application.yml` is correct.

I guess you still have a `version` property defined in your main `build.gradle`, which overrides the value set in the `gradle.properties` with value `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: How can i increment this version?